# Accessing a route parameter outside of <router-outlet>

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am writing a mock e-commerce application in Angular 11. My `app.component.html` has the following general structure:

```html
<mat-toolbar>
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <!-- Some buttons and links -->
    <button *ngIf="categoryName$ | async" [matMenuTriggerFor]="categories">{{categoryName$ | async}}</button>
    <!-- More buttons and links -->
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I defined the following routes:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginPage },
  { path: 'category/:categoryId', component: ShoppingPage },
  { path: 'checkout', component: CheckoutPage },
  { path: 'thankyou', component: ThankYouPage },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is to correctly display in the toolbar the user-friendly category name corresponding to the current `:categoryId` (provided, of course, that the current route is `/category/:categoryId`).

In `app.component.ts` I have a property called `categoryName$` which is a `Subject<string>`, that is supposed to emit a new string every time the route changes (an empty string if the route is not `/category/:categoryId`). To do that, I subscribe to `router.events` in `ngOnInit` as follows:

```js
this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
  if (event instanceof ActivationEnd) {
    const categoryId = event.snapshot.paramMap.get('categoryId');
    const categoryName = categoryId && categories.find(category => category._id === categoryId)?.name || '';
    this.categoryName$.next(categoryName);
  }
});
```

This works when I navigate from one category to another but not when I refresh the page, so in addition to that I tried to obtain `:categoryId` from the `ActivatedRoute` before subscribing to `router.events`:

```js
const categoryId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('categoryId');
```

But this doesn't work either. It returns `null` even though the URL is `http://localhost:4200/category/5fd1436490b05c22e80baaff`. (It *does* work in `ShoppingPage`, probably because it's rendered by `router-outlet`.)

So, how do I get around these limitations?

Comment: have you tried setting `paramsInheritanceStrategy: true` in your `forRoot()` router config? If that doesn't work, you need to use `this.route.snapshot.firstChild.paramMap`

Comment: @PoulKruijt The first thing didn't help and the second one didn't work because `this.route.snapshot.firstChild` was `null` (`this.route.snapshot.children` is an empty array).

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz? It will be much easier to help

Comment: @PoulKruijt Sure, here: https://stackblitz.com/github/zzmivbmkk?file=src/app/app.component.ts. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @PoulKruijt If you also need the server, you can temporarily see the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/roninbar/2020-11-05-online-shop/tree/refactor-pages). (Eventually I need to switch it back to private because it's a school assignment.)

Comment: The stackblitz link does not seem to work. At least for me

Comment: @PoulKruijt Sorry for that. Try this one: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-h9kt9a.

Comment: Eventually I decided it wasn't worth the headache and simply replaced the Category menu in `app.component.html` with a navbar inside the Shopping page.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit annoying the angular router. The access to child params can only happen when the navigation has finished. At the point that you are asking for the params, it has not finished yet. On the other hand, your solution also causes it to not be responsive to any category changes that might occur in the app. Now you have two ways to go about it:

Use an extra service, which you inject in the app component and in the child component, and from which the app component reads the current category, and the child component writes the current category.

Or you can use the following `Observable` in your `app-component` to get the current category name:

```
public categoryName$: Observable<string> = this.router.events.pipe(
  filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
  switchMap(() => this.route.firstChild?.params || of({})),
  map((params: any) => params.categoryId),
  filter((category) => !!category),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap((category) => this.getCategoryNameRx(category)),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

Comment: I'm trying your code. It doesn't work yet but I'm working on it.